# Backup in Ubuntu, upgrade and restore

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

I am using Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty) as a wubi installation in my laptop. i.e inside windows, in A drive. Now I need to move to another laptop. I found instructions for the backing up in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Now as a rule, I would be getting a new laptop with Windows again I need to use wubi. So in my new system I want to try 11.10 instead of 11.04

If I create a backup of 11.04 and in my new laptop if I upgrade to 11.10, can I restore it back in 11.10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest following: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_can_I_make_a_backup_of_my_Wubi_install.3F

In a nutshell, take a copy of the entire "disk image" that Wubi makes. It will take up a bit more space to keep, but you're guaranteed to get everything :)

Copy it over to your new Windows installation (you will have to install Wubi there first, to get everything setup, such as the Windows bootloader. Then rather than use the new disk image it just made, copy in your backup.

Once done you have 11.04 on your new laptop. Now upgrade it using the usual methods (`do-release-upgrade`, or `Update Manager`) to 11.10. There is little chance of this failing, but if it does, you still have the 11.04 backup image to fall back to (assuming you keep another copy of it, which you should until the upgrade is done).

Comment: Thanks caesium. do u mean to say, by "disk image" that if I installed ubuntu under "E:" in the name of "ubuntu" (the folder name), then I need to copy this entire folder from my old laptop and then in my new laptop using wubi installer copy this backup and then upgrade to 11.10?
Am i in the right track?

Comment: Almost. The only file you really need is the big disk image (called root.disk I think). But it wouldn't hurt to just keep it all. You will have to do a reinstall of the Wubi program on the new laptop anyway, so that the Windows bootloader is updated and so on. But once that's done, you can get your old Ubuntu system back by putting the large disk image back in place of the newer one.